# how can i access value of selected item's name which has value=xx with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have list of selectboxs like below.I want to access name of down to up first select box which one has value "a" selected.

when sb3 has selected values = b then if sb2 selected values =a I want o get this one else if sb1 selected values =a i want o get this one

when sb2 has selected values =b then if sb1 selected values =a I want o get this one and like so

I have tryed

```
console.log( $("[name^='sb'] option[value='a']:selected").closest('select').attr("name")  );
```

or

```
console.log( $(this).parent().closest( "[name^='sb'] option[value='ana']" ).attr("name") );
```

sample select lists;

```
<select name="sb1" >
<option value="a"></option>
<option value="b"></option>
</select>

<select name="sb2" >
<option value="a"></option>
<option value="b"></option>
</select>

<select name="sb3" >
<option value="a"></option>
<option value="b"></option>
</select>
```

edit anaother examle;

```
i want to get closest item prior to selested item.

sb45=a
sb46=a
sb47=b --> this give me sb46
sb48=b --> this give me sb46
sb49=a
sb50=b --> this give me sb49

thanks for help.
```

Comment: So, you want to be able to select those `select` tags whose value is `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a recurssive function wich iterate throw prev element and search for select with `value == a` otherwise no one selected .

```
function getRecursivePrevName($node) {
  $sb = $($node).prev("[name^='sb']");
  if($sb.length) {
    if($sb.val()=="a") return $sb.attr("name")
    else return getRecursivePrevName($sb);
  }
  else return null; 
}
```

Attaching the change handler will show wich sb* is selected ( priority from top to bottom )

See below snippet :

```js
$("[name^='sb']").on("change", function() {
  
  if($(this).val() !== 'a') {
     var value =  getRecursivePrevName($(this));
     console.log(value);
     if(value != null )
        $("#selected").html("select sb is <span style='color:red'>" + value + "</span>");
     else $("#selected").html("no select has value a");
  }else {
     console.log($(this).attr("name"));
     $("#selected").html("select sb is <span style='color:red'>" + $(this).attr("name") + "</span>");
  }
  
});

function getRecursivePrevName($node) {
  $sb = $($node).prev("[name^='sb']");
  if($sb.length) {
    if($sb.val()=="a") return $sb.attr("name")
    else return getRecursivePrevName($sb);
  }
  else return null; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sb1">
  <option></option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>

<select name="sb2">
  <option></option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>

<select name="sb3">
  <option></option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>

<select name="sb4">
  <option></option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>

<select name="sb5">
  <option></option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>

<select name="sb6">
  <option></option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>

<br><br>
<div id="selected">
<div>
```

Comment: i know it was hard to read / understand becaouse of me.

i want to get closest itemprior to selested item.
i mean, if sb3=b and both of sb2 and sb1 = a i want to get just sb2.

if i have sb50=b i need to get first sb* select box up to with value = a

 
sb45=a
sb46=a
sb47=b --> this give me sb46
sb48=b --> this give me sb46
sb49=a
sb50=b --> this give me sb49
 
thanks for help.

Comment: @AyY  I think I understand now , see my updated answer :)

Comment: thank you very much. this is very helpfull for me. best regards

Comment: @AyY you're Welcome :)